# Is everything in java EE abstract?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to java EE and, having some trouble understanding how java EE is implemented. According to the resources I have been using what I have understood is JAVA EE is just a collection of specifications, and application servers are the real implementation of those specifications.

Does it mean that architects at oracle, just came up with the design (just the skeleton: i.e interfaces, abstract classes, classes) and application server (Glassfish, WebLogic) programmers implemented this in real code?

Is everything in java EE just specifications?

What about JPA, JAX-RS? Does it mean, that application server vendors did not implement code for those specifications? If yes, does it also mean that application server vendors chose a subset of specification and implemented it in real code, and left some other specifications to be implemented by other vendors?

Comment: basically yes, EE is just specifications. but usually (always?) they publish also so called reference implementation with the spec. and if other vendors want to claim to be EE complaint, they have to pass tests e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

Comment: No it is programatically  tested before it is documented by oracle .Same hold for JAX-RS , JAX-WS ,JPA etc...

Comment: For example, GlassFish is the reference implementation for most JEE APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to nice @JoD.' s answer, few more thoughts:

> JAVA EE is just a collection of specifications, and application
>   servers are the real implementation of those specifications.

Exactly.

> Does it mean that architects at oracle, just came up with the design..

Architects at Sun, to be precise :)

> What about JPA, JAX-RS? Does it mean, that application server vendors
>   did not implement code for those specifications?

No. Every application server should implement all specifications in order to be Java EE-compliant. How they're gonna be implemented, that is vendor-specific. For example, WildFly's implementation of JPA is [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), but Glassfish uses [EclipseLink](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/). Both of them are superset of JPA, so if you stick just with classes that implement JPA, you are certain that your application can be deployed on various application servers without any additional actions. However, if you use classes from e.g. `org.eclipse.persistence.*` package, then you won't be able to deploy on WildFly unless you provide EclipseLink implementation together with your application.

Answer (score 2):

**Abstract Interfaces (API)**

The abstract interfaces allow you to compile your code into class/jar/war, without knowing or needing the exact implementation on the server you are deploying to. The Abstract Interfaces usually comprise of a standard (JEE,JCP).

Typically those interfaces are packed into libraries that will only be used at compile time (making sure your code can compile) without including them in your war distributable. During runtime, on the server, we will use whatever is already available and pre-installed.

Using maven dependencies, this is done by providing the `provided` scope, causing the library to be excluded from the packaging (war file).

Interfaces are typically named `*-api` like `java.faces-api-2.2.jar`.

**Implementation**

On the server side, we usually have the libraries already provided using an actual implementation as part of the Application Server. It is the implementation of a standard.

By separating the libraries with the Abstract Interfaces (the standard) from the libraries with a specific implementation, you will avoid compiling against vendor specific API's.

If the implementation is missing, you might choose to install it manually on the server (copying the jar to the right location), or by providing it as a maven dependency using the `runtime` scope. Maven will in that case make the libraries part of the packaging (war), but never compile against them. In that case you will still provide the api's using the `provided` scope as well.

Comment: do you mean that the jars which are named as "-api.jar" does not include the implementation code, but just the skeleton? then from where do we get the implementation code

Comment: The "-api.jar" does typically contain skeleton code. For the parts that need to be filled in (implementation), you buy a license or use open source. There is also usually a reference implementation (picked from open source sometimes). Example if you use JBoss, you dont jave to worry about the jee and java faces implementations, it is just there.